# Add fixed data fields to Salesforce -> Appflow -> Eventbridge configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, aws-event-bridge

To be able to reflect changes in Salesforce on my website, I use AWS Appflow and Eventbridge to trigger a Lambda which calls an API to update my website.

Currently, I can only see the changed fields in the event trigger, but I would like to be able to add a couple fields in the event from Salesforce that will always be sent with the event, such that I don't have to query the Salesforce API after the event trigger.

I have looked in both Appflow and Eventbridge, but couldn't find anything about it. There are questions on StackOverflow with answers that indicate it should be in the Appflow department, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Is this even possible?